# Using derivatives to get some trigonometric identities

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, reference-request

Is there a way of using derivatives to get some trigonometric identities in a straight-forward fashion? I use to forget them, so that would help me a lot...

For example, since when we get the derivative of the sine function we use the angle sum identity, maybe there is a way to get the angle sum identity from the derivative?

What I've considered is: We can think of $\sin (\alpha +\beta)=\sin \alpha \cos \beta + \sin \beta \cos \alpha$ as a function of two variables $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and so, maybe there is a theorem for functions of two variables that gives that form of formula. Is this correct? How can we do it? Any book or paper that discusses this?

Comment: you only need to have one of the letters as variable, and the other can be constant

Answer (score 5):

You can get them all from Euler's Identity: $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$.

For instance, consider $e^{i(\alpha+\beta)}$. I'm going to rewrite it and modify both equations separately:

$$e^{i(\alpha + \beta)} = e^{i\alpha}e^{i\beta}$$

$$\cos(\alpha+\beta) + i\sin(\alpha+\beta) = ( \cos\alpha + i\sin\alpha)( \cos\beta + i\sin\beta)$$

$$\cos(\alpha+\beta) + i\sin(\alpha+\beta) = \cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta+i\sin\alpha\cos\beta+i\sin\beta\cos\alpha$$

$$\color{blue}{\cos(\alpha+\beta)}+i\color{red}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)} = \color{blue}{(\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta)}+i\color{red}{(\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\beta\cos\alpha)}$$

Comment: That is a really elegant way to show the angle sum identities.

Comment: @Dylan: I know! I actually got excited over it since this was my first time ever seeing or deriving this one. Sine and cosine fall out for the *same* derivation, too!